# Algorithm for intersection between polyline and rectangle?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

My problem is simple, and probably obvious from the title itself, but I'll still clarify it a bit:

I have a rectangle and a polyline (array of N connected points). I need an optimal algorithm that checks if intersection between them exists (true/false).

Could someone please point me to one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The naïve algorithm (checking for all intersections between lines) seems optimal in terms of asymptotic complexity. You can't really get any better than linear.

Comment: I imagine if the array is sorted then it might be possible to do something that is logarithmic. A more natural place to ask this question is the CS.SE.